# Why is maven not downloading artifacts from specified repository

Tags: maven, repository, maven-archetype, artifact

I am running Maven 3.5 on Windows 10. Set two repositories in .m2/settings.xml

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>maven-release</name>
      <url>https://artifacts.repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-staging</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>maven-snapshots</name>
      <url>https://artifacts.repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Now I need to create a project from a custom quickstart archetype which was published in `maven-release` repo.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.lgc.dist -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=0.1 -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.foo -DartifactId=com.foo.example.firstservice -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DserviceName=FirstService -Dpackage=com.foo.example.firstservice
```

The quickstart artifact `com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart` is available at `https://artifacts.repo.openearth.community/artifactory/distarch-maven-staging/com/lgc/dist/com.lgc.dist.core.base.pom/0.1/com.lgc.dist.core.base.pom-0.1.pom`. Same goes for jar.

However the output of the mvn command shows it is trying to download from `apache.org` maven repository which was not defined anywhere in settings.xml file

```
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repsoitory with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/lgc/dist/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart/0.1/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart-0.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.lgc.dist:com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart:jar:0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/lgc/dist/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart/0.1/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart-0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.488 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-03T21:46:38-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.lgc.dist:com.lgc.dist.core.msp.quickstart:0.1) -> [Help 1]
```

I ran `mvn -X` to check which settings file it is using and it shows it was .m2/settings.xml. Why is it not working? Is there any special setup for windows 10? The same command works on a Linux VM with the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the archetypes weren't found in the repositories or the repositories could not be contacted then it says:

```
Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
```

You can avoid this behaviour if you set your repositories as *mirrors*.

Comment: All these two warnings are also found in the output of successful build on Linux VM. Set my repos to "mirrors", still the same

Answer (score -1):

because of security reasons, in the `maven 3.x` version, maven-archetype-plugin 3.x is not possible to particular repository from command line argument. you can refer this link http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-repository.html. you can use look below version

Comment: The same command works for Linux VM which has Maven 3.3.9 but does not work for Windows 10 with Maven 3.5.0. Settings.xml is same for both environment